# Find string between braces that can be broken by newlines

Tags: regex

Currently I am willing to walk through all the project PHP files and extract some language tokens from the source code to provide them for the translators (yep, the list of them was updated simultaneously but it happened that few tokens were missed).

The language strings can be written in all of the following cases:
**1. Single line**

```
translate('THIS IS MY LANGUAGE TOKEN I NEED TO EXTRACT')
```

**2. Token being on newline**

```
translate(
    'THIS IS MY LANGUAGE TOKEN I NEED TO EXTRACT'
)
```

**3. Token being on newline and split by newline(s)**

```
translate(
    'THIS IS '
    . 'MY LANGUAGE TOKEN '
    . 'I NEED TO EXTRACT'
)
```

I have came up with 2 regexes, first matching the case 1 and second matching the case 2, both returning `THIS IS MY LANGUAGE TOKEN I NEED TO EXTRACT` exactly:

1. `translate\([\'|"](.*)[\'|"]\)`
2. `translate\(\n[[:blank:]]*['|"](.*?)['|"]\n[[:blank:]]*\)`

I have a problem though to identify the third case and more importantly to match all three cases with just one regex match.

I was trying also the *lookbehind* and *lookahead* syntax, e.g. **`(?<=translate\()['|"](.*?)['|"](?=\))`** while matching only the first case of course (hadn't had luck to match the second nor third case with them either).

Is there anybody who could share the right regex (if any) or shed a little bit more light at least?

For those asking why it is not possible to have everything on one line only (so ending up with the case 1 only) - I am following the PSR-1 norm for PHP thus one line shall have maximum of 120 characters. Therefore splitting long strings onto multiple lines. But if there is no solution for just one simple regex I think I could temporarily break PSR-1, put all strings into one line matching the case 1 only, extract the tokens and revert changes. But this will take some time that I would like to save.

**Editors** - there is no need to add the PHP tag as this question is only regex related and has nothing to do with the PHP itself...

Comment: Can there be a nested brackets in your input? Also better let readers know in what language you are going to implement it. Just saying regex  is not enough since each regex flavor is different.

Comment: @anubhava OK, as mentioned in the first sentence, it's PHP. Brackets shouldn't be there in the tokens for 99.9999%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below regex pattern and get the matched group at index 1.  The regex pattern returns anything that is enclosed inside `(...)` followed by translate.

```
/translate\(\s*('[^\)]*')\s*\)/g
```

*Note:* change the regex as per your need. If you don't want single quotes to be part of group match then move it outside the parenthesis.

Here is demo on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/gN6lN8/3)

output:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [10-55] `'THIS IS MY LANGUAGE TOKEN I NEED TO EXTRACT'`
MATCH 2
1.  [73-118]    `'THIS IS MY LANGUAGE TOKEN I NEED TO EXTRACT'`
MATCH 3
1.  [137-200]   `'THIS IS ' . 'MY LANGUAGE TOKEN ' . 'I NEED TO EXTRACT'`
```

Comment: Changing your regex into this one `/translate\(\s*'([^\)]*)'\s*\)/g` I got rid of the apostrophes as well. Perfect!!! Thank you!

Comment: Only thing that this regex won't match nested brackets. OP wrote there are some 0.0001% inputs with this case :)

Comment: :-) I meant by that input that for now I know about no nested brackets and hopefully there will be no other in the future :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this PCRE recursive regex for matching:

```
'/translate \s* ( \( (?: [^()]* | (?1) )* \) )/x'
```

#### [Online regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/uL3yP4/1)

**Code:**

```
$re = "/translate \s* ( \( (?: [^()]* | (?1) )* \) )/x"; 

if (preg_match_all($re, $input, $matches))
    print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Works, which is very nice, but is there any chance to get rid of braces from the matched results? I.e., now the matched result is `('THIS IS ...')` but I would like to have `THIS IS ...` only - if it is not possible no problem...